# auto increment a column that is not a primary key when inserted

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a column on my database named `trackingcode` and it generates 3 random numbers when inserted to the database, is there a way or code where I could make it generate number in sequence? `eg. 001, 002 and so on...`

I thought about making it a primary key on my database so I could auto increment it but if there's a way to do it via coding then that'd be great.

Here's the insert code:

```js
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pcrequest");
if(isset($_POST["reqname"]))
{
 $length = 3;
 $trackingcode = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789"), 0, $length);
 $req_date = $_POST["req_date"];
 $reqname = $_POST["reqname"];
 $date = $_POST["date"];
 $empname = $_POST["empname"];
 $position = $_POST["position"];
 $account = $_POST["account"];
 $platform = $_POST["platform"];
 $processor = $_POST["processor"];
 $ram = $_POST["ram"];
 $monitor = $_POST["monitor"];
 $phone = $_POST["phone"];
 $phonetype = $_POST["phonetype"];
 $headset = $_POST["headset"];
 $req_table = $_POST["req_table"];
 $req_chair = $_POST["req_chair"];
 $approval = $_POST["approval"];
 $status = $_POST["status"];
 $query = '';
 

  for($count = 0; $count<count($reqname); $count++)
  {
  $req_date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_date[$count]);
  $reqname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $reqname[$count]);
  $date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $date[$count]);
  $empname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $empname[$count]);
  $position_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $position[$count]);
  $account_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $account[$count]);
  $platform_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $platform[$count]);
  $processor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $processor[$count]);
  $ram_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $ram[$count]);
  $monitor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $monitor[$count]);
  $phone_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phone[$count]);
  $phonetype_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phonetype[$count]);
  $headset_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $headset[$count]);
  $req_table_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_table[$count]);
  $req_chair_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_chair[$count]);
  $approval_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $approval[$count]);
  $status_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $status[$count]);
  if($req_date_clean != '' && $reqname_clean != '' && $date_clean != '' && $empname_clean != '' && $position_clean != '' && $account_clean != '' && $platform_clean != '' && $processor_clean != '' && $ram_clean != '' && $monitor_clean != '' && $phone_clean != '' && $phonetype_clean != '' && $headset_clean != '' && $req_table_clean != '' && $req_chair_clean != '' && $approval_clean != '' && $status_clean != '')
  {
   $query .= '
   INSERT INTO request(trackingcode, req_date, reqname, date, empname, position, account, platform, processor, ram, monitor, phone, phonetype, headset, req_table, req_chair, approval, status) 
   VALUES("'.$trackingcode.'", "'.$req_date_clean.'", "'.$reqname_clean.'", "'.$date_clean.'", "'.$empname_clean.'", "'.$position_clean.'", "'.$account_clean.'", "'.$platform_clean.'", "'.$processor_clean.'", "'.$ram_clean.'", "'.$monitor_clean.'", "'.$phone_clean.'", "'.$phonetype_clean.'", "'.$headset_clean.'", "'.$req_table_clean.'", "'.$req_chair_clean.'", "'.$approval_clean.'", "'.$status_clean.'"); 
   ';
  }
```

```html
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pcrequest");
if(isset($_POST["reqname"]))
{
 $length = 3;
 $trackingcode = str_pad($trackingcode, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
 $trackingcode++;
 $req_date = $_POST["req_date"];
 $reqname = $_POST["reqname"];
 $date = $_POST["date"];
 $empname = $_POST["empname"];
 $position = $_POST["position"];
 $account = $_POST["account"];
 $platform = $_POST["platform"];
 $processor = $_POST["processor"];
 $ram = $_POST["ram"];
 $monitor = $_POST["monitor"];
 $phone = $_POST["phone"];
 $phonetype = $_POST["phonetype"];
 $headset = $_POST["headset"];
 $req_table = $_POST["req_table"];
 $req_chair = $_POST["req_chair"];
 $approval = $_POST["approval"];
 $status = $_POST["status"];
 $query = '';
```

Comment: Why don't you add a database trigger for the target column? You could easily detect the row insert statement and action accordingly. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: @PedroBonifácioCosta I undestand, but I'm not really sure how I would incorporate it with my codes. I'm new to this and still learning

Comment: I think you should just make it a primary key; otherwise, you are either keeping track of a number, or you are always recalculating to get a number. Additionally, what happens if : 1) you reach a thousand rows, or 2) two numbers collide? You end up with a little to a lot of extra logic ...

Comment: @doordonot I'm very aware of the row numbers, don't worry. I just need to figure this out for now. Also, one more question, what if I wanted to put a prefix and then the number? `eg. req001`

Answer (score 0):

one way you could achieve something like this without updating your sql database is by retrieving the last tracking code and then using something like this to generate the next one :

#### PHP

```
// execute a statement like this
SELECT max(trackingcode) FROM your table
// increment the tracking code
$trackingcode++;
// format the tracking code before insertion
str_pad($trackingcode, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // 001
// then do your basic insert statement like the one above
```

You should consider adding an index to the trackingcode column for efficiency

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks! Should I put this above `if(isset($_POST["reqname"]))`?

Comment: You should always check if the value is set, and if it needs to be an array you should use if(isset($_POST["reqname"]) && is_array($_POST["reqname"])) { ... }

Comment: Not sure if I did it right, most probably wrong but please check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, hope it will help you.

```
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pcrequest");
    if(isset($_POST["reqname"]))
    {
    $length = 3;
    $req_date = $_POST["req_date"];
    $reqname = $_POST["reqname"];
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    $empname = $_POST["empname"];
    $position = $_POST["position"];
    $account = $_POST["account"];
    $platform = $_POST["platform"];
    $processor = $_POST["processor"];
    $ram = $_POST["ram"];
    $monitor = $_POST["monitor"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $phonetype = $_POST["phonetype"];
    $headset = $_POST["headset"];
    $req_table = $_POST["req_table"];
    $req_chair = $_POST["req_chair"];
    $approval = $_POST["approval"];
    $status = $_POST["status"];
    $query = '';


    for($count = 0; $count<count($reqname); $count++)
    {
    $req_date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_date[$count]);
    $reqname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $reqname[$count]);
    $date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $date[$count]);
    $empname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $empname[$count]);
    $position_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $position[$count]);
    $account_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $account[$count]);
    $platform_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $platform[$count]);
    $processor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $processor[$count]);
    $ram_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $ram[$count]);
    $monitor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $monitor[$count]);
    $phone_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phone[$count]);
    $phonetype_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phonetype[$count]);
    $headset_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $headset[$count]);
    $req_table_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_table[$count]);
    $req_chair_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_chair[$count]);
    $approval_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $approval[$count]);
    $status_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $status[$count]);
    }
    if($req_date_clean != '' && $reqname_clean != '' && $date_clean != '' && $empname_clean != '' && $position_clean != '' && $account_clean != '' && $platform_clean != '' && $processor_clean != '' && $ram_clean != '' && $monitor_clean != '' && $phone_clean != '' && $phonetype_clean != '' && $headset_clean != '' && $req_table_clean != '' && $req_chair_clean != '' && $approval_clean != '' && $status_clean != '')
    {
        $trackingQuery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Max(trackingcode) as maxtrack FROM `request`");
        if( mysqli_num_rows($trackingQuery) > 0)
        {
        $Newtracking = mysqli_fetch_assoc($trackingQuery)['maxtrack'] + 1 ;
        }
        else{
        $Newtracking = 1;
        }
        $query .= '
        INSERT INTO request(trackingcode, req_date, reqname, date, empname, position, account, platform, processor, ram, monitor, phone, phonetype, headset, req_table, req_chair, approval, status) 
        VALUES("'.$Newtracking.'", "'.$req_date_clean.'", "'.$reqname_clean.'", "'.$date_clean.'", "'.$empname_clean.'", "'.$position_clean.'", "'.$account_clean.'", "'.$platform_clean.'", "'.$processor_clean.'", "'.$ram_clean.'", "'.$monitor_clean.'", "'.$phone_clean.'", "'.$phonetype_clean.'", "'.$headset_clean.'", "'.$req_table_clean.'", "'.$req_chair_clean.'", "'.$approval_clean.'", "'.$status_clean.'"); 
        ';
    }

    }
```

Comment: it worked! thank you so much, what if I wanted to put a prefix then the number? like REQ001

Comment: try to output with prefix